# Spring form validation for plain HTML form

Tags: java, spring, validation, spring-mvc

I need to validate some simple forms in my application. In these forms I have one or two input text to validate so I'd like to not create a specific ModelAttribute class for every form. I'd like to use instead plain HTML form and use `@RequestParam` annotations to handle POST parameters.

Is there a way to use Spring form validation in this situation (without using model attribute) or should I implement a backing-form object and a validator for each form?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Currently it is not possible to use `@Valid` on individual `@RequestParam`, `@PathVariable` etc. to trigger validation. [This](https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-6380) is the relevant feature request on the Spring Issue Tracker. Let's cross our fingers for Spring 4.1!

In your case, you will either have to use `@ModelAttribute`, or perform custom validation inside the controller (or maybe a Spring interceptor if you want the same validation to apply to multiple endpoints)

Comment: Is it possible to use a `Map` as `ModelAttribute`?

Comment: You can use `Map<String,String>` to force Spring MVC to give you all the arguments, but I seriously doubt that validation will be run on it

Answer (score 1):

I think you can do this with Annotation. You can specifie for your parameters annotation like :

- @Size(min=3, max=5)
- @NotNull
- @NotEmpty

...

Answer (score 1):

Without a model attribute, Spring form Validation is not possible. Because Spring Form Validation depends on Spring Form Binding, which is a linkage between form elements and Model Attribute. So how small the form may be, create a DTO(Model Attribute), bind it to form and Perform Validations.

Answer (score 0):

Definitely not possible using Spring's validation API (Errors object):

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: An Errors/BindingResult argument is expected to be declared immediately after the model attribute, the @RequestBody or the @RequestPart arguments to which they apply
```

Answer (score 0):

You could instantiate a model object, fill it with the data from the plain form and validate that object programmatically.